# Create a list of entries and make each entry clickable

Tags: java, swing, list, jlist, jtree

I am trying to create an UI which has two panes.

In the left pane I display the list of files and right pane displays the contents.

Now, I want list of files in the left pane to look as a normal list. But when I click an entry in this list, the contents of the particular file should be displayed in the right pane.

How can I achieve this using Swing?

Comment: The files are created by another part of the program. So, I am sure that the files are readable ASCII files.

Answer (score 5):

Here I have done a short example, with the help of `JList` on the left and `JTextArea` on right. I have used `ListSelectionListener` to get the item list change. Use a `LayoutManager` as per your convenience.

[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class JListTest {

    private JList jList1;
    private JPanel jPanel1;
    private JTextArea jTextArea1;

    public JListTest() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        jPanel1 = new JPanel();
        jList1 = new JList();
        jTextArea1 = new JTextArea();

        jList1.setModel(new AbstractListModel() {

            String[] strings = {"Item 1", "Item 2"};

            @Override
            public int getSize() {
                return strings.length;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getElementAt(int i) {
                return strings[i];
            }
        });
        jList1.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt) {
                jList1ValueChanged(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);

        jPanel1.add(jList1);
        jPanel1.add(jTextArea1);
         f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(jPanel1);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void jList1ValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {
        //set text on right here
        String s = (String) jList1.getSelectedValue();
        if (s.equals("Item 1")) {
            jTextArea1.setText("You clicked on list 1");
        }
        if (s.equals("Item 2")) {
            jTextArea1.setText("You clicked on list 2");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JListTest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/). Note `pack()` _before_ `setVisible()` and more sparing use of white space. Also consider `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`.

Comment: @trashgod thanks for the edit. `JList.addListSelectionListener` is invoked 2 times as soon as you click,but, you cannot make out just by looking at the interface because i am just setting the text on `JTextArea`, any reasons?,`EXIT_ON_CLOSE` edited :)

Comment: Print `evt.getValueIsAdjusting()` and watch as you click and drag over the list.

Comment: @trashgod oh god! thanks! was not even knowing that function exist! :)

Answer (score 3):

Check out [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). It explains how to use lists in Swing, including [event handlers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#selection) that are necessary to register for click events.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at this [JTree example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#create).

Answer (score 3):

first off, you have not even tried yet, right? Swing does almost everything input related with listeneres. Check out the mouse listener, or adjust the awnser giving below

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4344762/258418

For completness I quote it here:

```
String[] items = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
JList list = new JList(items);

list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
        JList list = (JList)evt.getSource();
        if (evt.getClickCount() == 2) {
            int index = list.locationToIndex(evt.getPoint());
        } else if (evt.getClickCount() == 3) {   // Triple-click
            int index = list.locationToIndex(evt.getPoint());

        }
    }
});
```

I am sure you can make it take single clicks as well,... if not write a comment

Comment: The `JList` API suggests a `MouseListener` / `MouseAdapter` for multiple clicks, but wouldn't a `ListSelectionListener` be better for single clicks?

Comment: I guess you are right... (unless I construct something absurd where doubleclicking is needed to change the selection, and singleclicking displays info)

Comment: A `ListSelectionListener` also sees keyboard navigation, and there can be multiple listeners.

Answer (score 3):

Some examples for reference:

- [`FileBrowser`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/6692) uses a `JTree` on the left and nested detail panels on the right.
- [`ImageDisplay`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4054307/230513) embeds a custom `JFileChooser` on the left and displays a scrollable image on the right.
- [`CheckTable`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13919878/230513) shows a `JTable` on the left and a `DisplayPanel` on the right.

Answer (score 3):

Use `JList.addListSelectionListener(ListSelectionListener)`.

See [*How to Write a List Selection Listener*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) for more [examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html#eg).