# How to select a image from a JFrame and then upload it to imgur?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have done some browsing on the internet and have found this code showing how to display multiple photos in a JFrame as seen below. What I want to be able to do is select a photo and be able to upload it to imgur through clicking a button. I know how to upload files to imgur through java but I don't know how to select one image. Anyone Have a Solution?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ListView {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String path = "C:/Users/Photos";
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    File folder = new File(path);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("check path"+listOfFiles[i]);
        String name = listOfFiles[i].toString();
        // load only JPEGs
        if ( name.endsWith("png") ) {
            ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(listOfFiles[i]));
            listModel.add(count++, ii);
        }
    }
    JList lsm=new JList(listModel);
    lsm.setVisibleRowCount(1);

    frame.add(new JScrollPane(lsm));

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Hope this helps! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344682/double-click-event-on-jlist-element

Comment: A self explanatory title would be: How to select an image from JList (instead of JFrame)

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know how to select one image.

- `JList` uses  an instance of `ListSelectionModel` to manage its selection. By default, a list selection model allows any combination of items to be selected at a time. You can specify a different selection mode(i.e, *single item selection*) by calling the [`setSelectionMode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setSelectionMode%28int%29) method on the list.

  ```
   jList1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
  ```
- To do, on item selection event with `JList`,  use the `ListSelectionListener` to select your item.

  ```
   jList1.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

          @Override
          public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
           JList jlist = (JList) e.getSource();
           Object curentSelectedObject = jlist.getModel().getElementAt(e.getFirstIndex());
           Object lastSelectedObject = jlist.getModel().getElementAt(e.getLastIndex());
          }
      });
  ```

Using `ListSelectionListener` is preferable over using `MouseListener` with `JList`. Unlike `MouseListener`, being simple and higher level, it has other two functions `evt.getFirstIndex()` and `evt.getLastIndex()` which is very useful.

**Tutorial resource:**

1. [How to Write a List Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you need get what was selected in your list, you can use something like this in event handler:

```
    ImageIcon selected = (ImageIcon)lsm.getSelectedValue();
    if(selected == null){
         // nothing selected
    }else{
         // something is selected
    }
```