# How do I make seesaw listbox react to double-click?

Tags: clojure, seesaw

Okay, so this may be a silly one, but I am at such a loss that I created a SOF account for that.
Here's a thing that does almost what I want:

```
(let [lb (listbox :model ["a" "b" "c"])]
  (listen lb :selection
    (fn [e] (alert (selection lb))))
(-> (frame :content lb)
  pack! show!))
```

If you run this code you'll see a listbox with three entries (a, b, c). If you click on any one of them an alert pops up with that entry in it.
What I want to do is make the listbox react in this way to DOUBLE-clicks, not single-clicks. How should I go about it?

Extra kudos to those who tell me how to make the number of the double-clicked item appear in the popup (0 for a, 1 for b, 2 for c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seesaw's `listbox` function returns a [`JList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html).  A `JList`'s [`ListSelectionModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html) does not provide a way to determine whether the [`ListSelectionEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionEvent.html) was the result of a double-click.  So a `:selection` listener won't help here.

On the other-hand, `MouseEvent` does provide `getClickCount`, which can be used to detect a double-click.  So you can use a `:mouse-clicked` listener instead, and filter for double-clicks.  Then all you need to do is find the `ListItem` that corresponds with the click location.  Fortunately, `JList` provides a `locationToIndex` method that can be used for this purpose.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4344762/440294) to "[Double-click event on JList element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4344682/440294)" puts those pieces together for Java.  A translation to Clojure/Seesaw would look something like this:

```
(listen lb :mouse-clicked
        (fn [ev]
          (when (= 2 (. ev getClickCount))
            (let [index (. list locationToIndex (. ev getPoint))]
              <... do something with the index / list item ...>))))
```